# sharing my app through facebook in corona Sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm beginner to corona sdk and programming , I want to share my app via facebook to my freinds.I want a button that connects to the facebook through my app and my default message will be send to my freinds.Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What do Corona SDK applications have to do with Facebook applications? As far as I can tell, they are a completely different thing...

Comment: I want to share my corona app or send a default message to my freinds on facebook through my corona SDK app.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Ghosts vs Monsters sample/template on the Corona SDK website.